# Why is [Object] printed to the console in node.js instead of an object's contents?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to access each individual song in a playlist object returned by the spotify API. When I get the JSON object, it returns me a bunch of [Object] things in "items", which is where the tracks should be:

```
spotifyApi.getPlaylist(id, listID)
    .then(function (data) {
        // printing data from this line
        console.log('The playlist contains these tracks', data.body);
    }, function (err) {
        console.log('Something went wrong!', err);
    });
```

output:

```
Playlist name : thug lif3  Playlist ID: 41moBc7H5bWrR3iiY0Zu9Q
The playlist contains these tracks {
    /*~~~ lots of skipped output ~~~*/
    { href: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/...',
        /*~~~        why [Object]?            ~~~*/
        items: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
        limit: 100
    },
}
```

Are these [object] things a sign of a nullity, or is there some way I can parse them and get the data from them? The API explorer on Spotify's website shows the actual track objects after "Items", so I'm confused as to why my app request isn't doing the same.

Comment: I removed all the extra code and output from question. In the future, try to limit code samples/output to just what pertains to the problem at hand. It makes questions more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You can have `console.log` output proper JSON:

```
console.log('The playlist contains these tracks %j', data.body);
```

(the `%j` is documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format)).

The regular output that `console.log` generates for objects isn't proper JSON, and also limited to a certain object depth; after that, you'll get the `[Object]` strings.

Answer (score 1):

That's just how deeply nested objects are printed to node's console. They're still available programmatically. In your case, use `data.body.tracks.items` to access the objects.

If you want a pretty-printer, you can use [bunyan](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan), which'll make nested objects (and everything else) look really nice in the console.

Answer (score 1):

This is the rather normal behaviour of node. Either drill down programmatically or use `util.inspect` [link](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
var util = require('util');
...
spotifyApi.getPlaylist(id, listID)
    .then(function (data) {
        // printing data from this line
        console.log('The playlist contains these tracks', util.inspect(data.body, { showHidden: true, depth: null });
    }, function (err) {
        console.log('Something went wrong!', err);
    });
```